# How do I use one shape to delete a portion of another shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I have created an arrow shape (rightmost in image), from which I wish to cut out the majority so that only two thin sides remain. The most accurate way to do this would be to duplicate the shape and to somehow use the duplicate (leftmost in image) to remove the chunk that I no longer desire from the original. I am not sure what to do after the duplication, however, or if this method is even possible? Is there a better one?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a shape, in a form of two basic shapes partially substracted?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-to-create-a-shape-in-a-form-of-two-basic-shapes-partially-substracted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty much on the right track.

You could do it like this:

1. Create the triangle shape ( Or in your case, delete the second triangle, you only need one at this point ).

   [image]
2. Take `Path selection tool` and click the triangle once and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow key</kbd>.

   - **Left arrow key**: Moves the path to the left
   - **Shift**: Makes sure that the 1 <kbd>Left arrow key</kbd> click equals 10px to the left.
   - **Alt**: Makes sure that when the left arrow key is clicked, the currently selected shape is copied as well

   ( after that you may want to press **just the the arrow keys** few more
   times to position it perfectly... )

   [image]
3. From the tool options you will find icon for path operations. Select: `Subtract front shape`( In older versions these icons will all be in the tool options sitting side by side, because that's how they roll... )

   [image]

   ...that will subtract from the previous path.

   [image]

   [image]

---

This all happens inside one shape layer:

[image]

---

...and the same method works in older versions as well, as long as you start with a shape layer.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I'd forgotten I could activate the paths on a shape layer with the path selection tool :/

Comment: Note, both shapes need to be in the same shape layer. If they’re not, right click on them, select “Merge Shapes”, then perform the above.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the image preview box in the layers window for the layer of the image you want to use as the cookie cutter. Click select pixels. Now click or select the layer you want to chop a hole in, then go ahead and ctrl-X, or cut pixels.

You will need to rasterize your shapes before doing this if you haven't already.