# How to achieve a chevron color mask effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I was browsing the Strava challenges page and noticed the following design:

[image]

I like the way the chevron design has a color masking effect on the circles.

I imagine illustrator would be a better software choice due to its superior vector tools, but how would one achieve this effect in Photoshop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways, but I might use `Clipping mask` to mask out everything that is outside the circles.

I made one arrow and duplicated it. I also Linked the arrows, so that they can be moved freely, as shown in the gif below.

Yellow arrow is in a clipping mask with `Circle - RED` and Red arrow is in clipping mask with `Circle - BLACK`.

[image]
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: wouldnt this eliminate the vector nature on print?

Comment: Thanks, even though you have uses raster shapes I find the same method can be used with vector shapes. Could you explain how you constructed the arrows? What's a good way of doing it with vectors?

Comment: @harryg Harryg, The way I made the arrows is nearly identical to [**this answer**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/how-do-i-use-one-shape-to-delete-a-portion-of-another-shape/17620#17620). The only real difference being that I used `Rectangle tool` for the shape.