# How can I create this shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

[image]

I want to create a scalable version of the shape above in Photoshop. I tried creating a path and filling the stroke but that wasn't very smooth. Is there a way of creating this as a vector or something? Thanks in advance!

P.s. I'm using CS4

Comment: This is actually not very easy to make as a Shape element in photoshop cs 4. In fact, this is kinda difficult to make in any version of photoshop ( **assuming that the slight corner radius that I'm seeing is real** and not an illusion ). If you have illustrator, that's what you should use to do this.

Comment: If you don't want the rounded corners, it's pretty simple. [You could use this method](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/how-do-i-use-one-shape-to-delete-a-portion-of-another-shape/17620#17620).  In step 2, just replace the shift+alt+arrow key shortcut with copy&paste and before step 3, use Free transform to make the pasted shape smaller. Then just draw another path to subtract one of the sides. Or extend the inner path with pen tool. Either way, it's easier in Illustrator. Vector elements can be copy&pasted from Illustator into PS as shapes or vector smart objects.

Comment: Thanks Joonas. Really wanted the round corners too. Will try and do it on illustrator. Appreciate your help!

Comment: There are other ways to do this in Illustrator, especially in the newer versions, but this should work for you: **1.** Apply `Effects > Stylize > Round corners...` to your shape. **2.** Use `Direct selection tool` to select one of the sides. Delete it. **3.** In the `Window > Stroke`, select a round end `Cap`.

Comment: I just wanted to ask that why creating such shape in Photoshop is much, why you aren't trying this in illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would definitely be easier to do in Illustrator, since there you can use Stroke, which then can be expanded to Fill.

But here's how I would do this in Photoshop
Notice: You'll need “[Corner Editor](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/)” script by @shadowxaf

Using `Polygon Tool` with `6` sides ([image: polygon tool]) create two shapes (use `Shift` to align it properly):

[image: Polygons]

Apply rounded corner to the first polygon using `Corner Editor` script:

[image: Outer Polygon]

Apply smaller radius of rounded corner to the second polygon:

[image: Inner Polygon]

Now subtract smaller polygon from the bigger one:

[image: Polygon Subtraction Process]

And here's a bit tricky part. We need to cut one of the sides of the polygon, here's a process of doing this:

[image: Polygon Cut Process]

You can alter round corner radius (mine was too big) and sizes of polygons on each step to make it look more like the shape you need:

[image: Final Shape]

And that's it. Hope it will help!
But again, this would be a much easier to do in Adobe Illustrator (it can do few of the steps above automatically)

Comment: Thanks a lot darkwark! Really great guide. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you choose the custom shape tool, you could choose the hexagon and draw out a vector version. Then, by pressing A on your keyboard, or I get the point selection tool, you could delete the bottom left line from the shape. Then, from the fill and stroke options you could turn off the fill and choose a stroke colour and weight...

This would give you a vector version of the shape you want.

Then if you right click the layer and convert it to a smart object, when you scale it the stroke will scale with it.

[image: Steps for the above]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunatley, this doesn't leave a gap in the cut out edge, photoshop joins the edges for the stroke

Comment: It should definitely work, I have edited my answer to show the steps in photoshop. I hope this helps.

Comment: This being said, I have just noticed the corner radius on the anchor points, if those corner radius' are not just a blur and are actually there, and they need to be there, then I would definitely go with Darkwark's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this using line tool as shape, put the guides you need as anchor and it is done really quick, not need to work on hexagons.

[image]

Comment: I'd argue that in this case creating an hexagon first is much easier, the shape OP asks for IS an hexagon just missing one segment. You'll have much more work to get your shape correctly.

Comment: @Luciano my shape is incorrect since I stretched it, was just to give an idea, you can draw lines and make a symmetric hexagon leaving the last segment.